# Why doesn't this parseFloat work?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I'm very new to JavaScript so excuse my newbiness. But I'm currently running this code, to test some stuff out

```
var firstNumber = prompt("enter the first number ");
var secondNumber = prompt("enter the second number ");
var theTotal = firstNumber + secondNumber;
firstNumber = parseFloat(firstNumber);
secondNumber = parseFloat(secondNumber);
document.write(firstNumber + " added to " + secondNumber + " equals " +    theTotal);
```

Why doesn't that add the numbers up correctly? I know the proper way of doing it would be to wrap the parseFloat around the prompt, but I just want to know why this doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When execute to `var theTotal = firstNumber + secondNumber;` you just combined 2 `string` and assign it to `theTotal`, please put this line after you parse the numbers.

Comment: `firstNumber + secondNumber` are adding `strings`... try to `firstNumber*1 + secondNumber*1` to convert it quick to number and see the result if is the answer I will add it as answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse should be done before doing the add operation:

```
var firstNumber = prompt("enter the first number ");
var secondNumber = prompt("enter the second number ");
firstNumber = parseFloat(firstNumber);
secondNumber = parseFloat(secondNumber);
var theTotal = firstNumber + secondNumber;
document.write(firstNumber + " added to " + secondNumber + " equals " +    theTotal)
```

Answer (score 0):

`firstNumber + secondNumber` are adding `strings`... try to `firstNumber*1 + secondNumber*1` to convert it quick to number and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

When you add firstNumber to secondNumber, they're still strings; you're not converting them to numbers until after the addition.  Do this instead:

```
firstNumber = parseFloat(firstNumber);
secondNumber = parseFloat(secondNumber);
var theTotal = firstNumber + secondNumber;
document.write(firstNumber + " added to " + secondNumber + " equals " +    theTotal);
```